# Which of these languages is regular? The Pumping Lemma seems to show none are

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I've been reviewing past paper questions for an automaton course, and came across a question which effectively asks, which of these languages is regular?
$$
\{\ 0^m1^{(m \times n)}0^n\ \colon\ m,n\ge 0\}\
$$
$$
\{\ 0^m1^{2m}0^m\ \colon\ m \geq 0\}\
$$
$$
\{\ 0^m1^n0^m\ \colon\ m\ge 0\ \&\ 0 \le n \le 1\}\
$$
$$
\{\ 0^mw\ \colon\ m\ge 0\ \&\ w \in \{0,1\}^*\ \&\ w\ \text{contains at least m 0's} \}\
$$
I have tried to apply the Pumping Lemma, but all my proofs seem to show these languages are not regular. I highly doubt the question is wrong, as the examiners' report makes not mention of it. Can anyone help be figure out which is regular?

Comment: In the last one, nothing requires tgat $w$ start with a $1$. Furthermore, $m$ can be $0$. So what is not part of the language?

Comment: Put it down to experience: Just because you have a "proof" doesn't mean it's true :-) The last one is a very simple language written in a very complicated way.

Comment: Yeah, that last language was studied here: [Is this language regular or not?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/8991/4287). (And I had to delete my mistaken answer, six years ago.)